# Git Repository within Git Repository for Client Consumption of Distribution Files

Tags: git, webpack, packaging

I have a webpack project that creates files in the `dist` folder. I want my client to have access to only the files in the dist folder and would like them to be able to install and update via the git command line. So I have

```
+project
  +dist
     -main.js
     -vendor.js
     -index.html
     -README.md
  +src
     -index.js
     -index.html
     ...
```

So I would like my project to be one git repository. Only I would have access to this repo. I would like the `dist` folder to be another git repo that I can provide to the client.

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Why should your client be able to install "via the Git command line"? There are other tools that are more suited to distributing and deploying releases.

Comment: Ok. What would you recommend I use then? This is a script they will install in one location on their server and pull into web surveys as they see fit.

Comment: At that point it becomes a language-and-ecosystem question, not a Git question. I'm not a JS developer, but you might consider hosting a private NPM package or using GitHub releases or something. (You could probably make something work with Git itself, but IMO committing compiled build artifacts is an anti-pattern.)